# Dagger2 singleton annotation not working

Tags: android, dagger-2

So, a bit of context. I'm using Dagger2, Retrofit and RxAndroid and structuring my app using an MVP architecture.

For now, all I'm doing is making a network request to the API a retrieving some information as soon as my main activity starts. I'm trying to persist my presenters through configuration changes to avoid making a new http request every time I rotate my screen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ForecastView {


@Inject
Presenter forecastPresenter;

private TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initializeDependencies();
    initializePresenter();
}

private void initializeDependencies() {
    DaggerWeatherApiComponent.builder()
            .build().inject(this);
}

private void initializePresenter() {
    forecastPresenter.attachView(this);
    forecastPresenter.onCreate();

}
```

**WeatherApiComponent.java**

```
@Component(modules = {EndpointsModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface WeatherApiComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity context);
}
```

**EndpointsModule.java**

```
@Module @Singleton
public class EndpointsModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    WeatherEndpoints provideEndpoints() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(WeatherEndpoints.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Repository providesRepository(RestRepository repository) {
        return repository;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Presenter providesPresenter(ForecastPresenter presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

**RestRespository**

```
public class RestRepository implements Repository {
    private WeatherEndpoints endpoints;
    static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Inject
    public RestRepository(WeatherEndpoints endpoints) {
        this.endpoints = endpoints;
    }

    public Observable<Current> getCurrentWeather(String cityName) {
        return endpoints.getCurrent(cityName, API_KEY);
    }

    public Observable<com.feresr.rxweather.models.List> getForecast(String cityName) {
        return endpoints.getForecast(cityName, API_KEY).flatMap(new Func1<FiveDays, Observable<com.feresr.rxweather.models.List>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<com.feresr.rxweather.models.List> call(FiveDays fiveDays) {
                return Observable.from(fiveDays.getList());
            }
        });
    }
```

}

**ForecastPresenter.java**

```
public class ForecastPresenter implements Presenter {
private GetForecastUseCase useCase;
private Subscription forecastSubscription;
private ArrayList<List> lists;
private ForecastView forecastView;

@Inject
public ForecastPresenter(GetForecastUseCase forecastUseCase) {
    this.useCase = forecastUseCase;
    lists = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (forecastSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        forecastSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}

@Override
public void attachView(View v) {
    forecastView = (ForecastView) v;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    if (lists.isEmpty()) {
        forecastSubscription = useCase.execute().subscribe(new Action1<List>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List list) {
                lists.add(list);
                forecastView.addForecast(list.getWeather().get(0).getMain());
            }
        });
    } else {
        forecastView.addForecast(lists.get(0).toString());
    }
}
```

The constructor on this class (presenter) keeps calling itself as I rotate my Acitivity. I've annotated with @Singleton most of my classes. I don't know what else to do.

EDIT: Note that I haven't gotten into dagger SCOPES just yet, for now I don't care if this singleton presenter lives as long as my app. I'll fix that later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're recreating the Dagger component every time `MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle)` is called, and the activity is reinstantiated when you rotate the screen.

Like other scopes, `@Singleton` means there will be one instance of the object *for the lifetime of the component*, not for the lifetime of the JVM. You typically have to make sure there is only one instance of the `@Singleton` component yourself, usually by keeping it in a field in your `Application`.

Comment: Oh!, so... why do we bother annotating Components and modules with the @singleton annotation?

Comment: Adding a scope annotation to a `@Provides` method means that the method will be called at most once within one instance of the component it's installed into.

Without that, the `@Provides` method would be called again every time a `Provider`'s `get()` method is called, even within one component instance. Every class that `@Injects` a `RestRepository` would get a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new dagger component every time here:

```
private void initializeDependencies() {
    DaggerWeatherApiComponent.builder()
            .build().inject(this);
}
```

A scoped dependency exists as ONE instance PER component.

If you create a new component, it will have its own scope, and it will create its own instance.

You should either invest in `Mortar` scopes to preserve your component, or you should have some sort of "cache" in your `Application` instance.